# How to inject a constant from other module into config section in angular js?

Tags: angularjs

Lets say I have a app with three modules, such as

***//constants module***

```
  angular.module("appConstants", []).constant('temp', {
      amazing: 'amazing'
    });
```

***//app directives module***

```
 angular.module("app.directive", []).config(['$injector', function ($injector){
            var const = $injector.get('appConstants');
    })
```

***//app module***

```
  angular.module("app", ['appConstants', 'app.directive']);
```

Here even though I have injected the appConstants in app level, directives are not able to access it.

Any reason why it not possible to inject in this way to config, but If I inject in service it works.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried injecting just the constant itself?

Comment: yes that works, but I wanted something without it, i got it working by changing the order :)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$scope.const = $injector.get('appConstants');`?

Comment: no, no required..